# Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

i am facing few issues during an application of Codeigniter -- Created an function like

```
function searchUnivtab() {
        $country = $this->input->post('countryKey');
        $state = $this->input->post('stateKey');
        $level = $this->input->post('level');
        $degType = $this->input->post('degType');       
        $country = str_replace('%20', ' ', $country);
        $state = str_replace('%20', ' ', $state);
        $degType = explode('~', $degType);
        $data = @$this->get->getSearchedUniversityTab($country, $state, $level, $degType[1]);
        $html = '';
        $i = 0;
        foreach($data as $d)
        {
            $html .= '<option value="'.$d['name'].'">'.$d['name'].'</option>';
        }
        echo $html; die;
    }
```

Error as:  `A PHP Error was encountered`

`Severity: Warning`

`Message:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`, `Line Number: 270` which is at `foreach` line

Any help related to above code ?

Comment: are you sure the $data is array ( i havent use the codeigniter )?

Comment: @NullPointer No sir, its not an array, Print 'data is not an array.'

Comment: Okie, if i removed, how can i fetch the values of $data ? any help ? code is same as above--

Comment: The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays. foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable.

Comment: what do get in $data ? can you show to us ?

Comment: Hi, its not allowing me to post the code of larger characters, here is the url of $data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448420/error-during-execution-of-this-function

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19740/discussion-between-nikita-chopra-and-nullpointer)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function getSearchUniversity() {
  country = jQuery('[name=countryKey]').val();
  state = jQuery('[name=stateKey]').val();
  level= jQuery('[name=level]').val();
  degType= jQuery('[name=degType]').val();
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:baseurl+ 'welcome/searchUnivtab', 
    cache: false,
    data: {countryKey: country, stateKey: state, level: level, degType: degType},
    error: function()
    {
      //notify('Error: Your request could be processed.. try again..!!');
    },
    success: function(html)
    {
      jQuery('[name=universityList]').html(html);
      return false;
    }
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove @ in the following line to see if it produces any error
so replace

```
$data = @$this->get->getSearchedUniversityTab($country, $state, $level, $degType[1]);
```

with

```
$data = $this->get->getSearchedUniversityTab($country, $state, $level, $degType[1]);
```

Comment: thankyou so much, its work, but error has been changed to Message:  Undefined offset:  1

Comment: so your error is basically else where. Post field degType is expecting a value which is exploded using ~, what is the value you are posting?

Comment: Its showing at line 267, $data = $this->get->getSearchedUniversityTab($country, $state, $level, $degType[1]);

Comment: As I mentioned above, the value expected in the post field degType is then broken down using ~ (so the value could be something like abc~def, script tries to convert it to an array and fails, which is what the second error you got

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_array($data)) {
    foreach($data as $d){
        $html .= '<option value="'.$d['name'].'">'.$d['name'].'</option>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'data is not an array.';
}
```