# Error during execution of this function

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448152/message-invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach-in-codeigniter)

Continue from [Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448152/message-invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach-in-codeigniter).

This is the function, from which the $datais coming..

```
function getSearchedUniversityTab($country, $state, $level, $degType) {
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT `university`.`uniId`, `university`.`name`
                                FROM (`university`)
                                inner JOIN (select degCollege, degType, count(*) as cnt  from degree where `degType` =  '$degType'  group by degCollege) clg
                                ON clg.`degCollege` = `university`.`uniId` 
                                WHERE `country` =  '$country'
                                AND `state` =  '$state'");
      $result = $query->result_array();

      foreach($result as $row)
      {
        $data[] = $row;
      }
      return $data;
      $this->db->close();  
   }
```

Comment: If you've got errors, include them as quoted parts of your question - it's easier for all to read...

Comment: And what do you want to know?

Comment: Since this is the same problem as your last question you should just update the last one.

Comment: @EmilVikström yes you are right.

Comment: Regrets, Its not worked again... :(

Comment: Did someone already inform you that your code is wide open for SQL injection?

Comment: Sql Query is typically fetching the right results, if puts in Database--- NO response in frontend..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probable your `result` is returning empty
Change to

```
function getSearchedUniversityTab($country, $state, $level, $degType) {
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT `university`.`uniId`, `university`.`name`
                                FROM (`university`)
                                inner JOIN (select degCollege, degType, count(*) as cnt  from degree where `degType` =  '$degType'  group by degCollege) clg
                                ON clg.`degCollege` = `university`.`uniId` 
                                WHERE `country` =  '$country'
                                AND `state` =  '$state'");
      $result = $query->result_array();
     if(count($result) > 0 ) {
      foreach($result as $row)
      {
        $data[] = $row;
      }

      return $data;
     }else{
       return null;
     }
      $this->db->close();  
   }
```